# How to display data from mongoDB using mongoose node and angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I have a problem with display data from DB because in res I have null.
In angular, I made Http.get to response data from ProductView, whose download JSON with data from database and nothing.

Angular:

```
$scope.productView = function (id) {
    console.log(id);
    $http.get("/product/productView", { 'id': id }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.product = resp.data;
        console.log(resp.data);
    })
};
```

Node:

```
router.get('/product/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('product/product', { title: 'Express', id: req.params.id });
});


router.get('/productView', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  products.findById(req.body.id).exec(function (err, products) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: 'File Not Found 404'
      })
    } else {
         res.json(products);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `router.get('/prouctView'....)` to `router.get('/product/productView'...)`?

Comment: where u seen prouctView

Comment: GOB is talking about this line: `router.get('/productView', function (req, res, next) {`

which doesn't match this line.... `$http.get("/product/productView", { 'id': id }).then(function (resp) {`